# Apache 2.4 not serving correct virtual host

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

So I am attempting to configure apache to do two things: serve a mod_wsgi application on the host and act as a reverse proxy for a web server running inside a vm on the host.  To do this, I am using name-based virtual hosts in apache.  This is my vhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/site1.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certs/site1.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/site1CA.crt

    ServerName site1.com

    Alias /static /static
    <Directory /static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /wsgi/files >
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess webapp python-path=/wsgi/files
    WSGIProcessGroup webapp
    WSGIScriptAlias / /wsgi/files/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / https://<local vm ip>/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://<local vm ip>/
    ServerName site2.com
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/site2.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certs/site2.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/site2CA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

The output of `apache2 -S` is:

```
<host ip>:443        is a NameVirtualHost
     default server site1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/vhosts.conf:1)
     port 443 namevhost site1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/vhosts.conf:1)
     port 443 namevhost site2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/vhosts.conf:29)
```

I have confirmed that the DNS entry for site1.com and site2.com are the same ip.  But when I try to navigate to site1.com, it always brings up site2.com.  However, if on the host server I do `curl https://site1.com` it correctly shows site1.com.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: If I disable https on site1.com and have it listen on port 80, it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be an iptables NAT rule that forwarded all traffic over port 443 to site2.com, which is why that was getting served regardless.